# Good practice for including headers in each module

Tags: c

Assuming that I have 3 source files for an exe in C. Is it a good practice to include headers like stdio in all the three and also in the source file which contains the main() function?

If NO then what is the normal practice.

I read an article which says the header should contain all the definitions of the structures, #defines etc. But I not sure about including other standard headers.

Any suggestions is appreciated!

Comment: @SteveJessop Sure. Edited the same as per advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include only headers, you need. And no others.

---

Including additional headers, that are not necessary, may/will produce unnecessary larger exe/lib. You don't need that.

Also, this could be misleading for somebody - don't include code, that you don't need.

It could cause name conflicts, for example - if you include headers, containing functions, with the same name. You don't need this, too.

`C` does not have `namespace`s, so you don't need to include names, you will not use. You may want to use them for other things.

If you need a header in several modules - include it. Otherwise:

- if it's not included indirectly, you'll have compiler errors.
- if it IS included indirectly, this could cause some troubles for the developers, who will maintain/support your code

Comment: So you mean to say if I need to include stdio in all the 3 modules then I  should include in all the three. is it?